# Points with power distances

Tags: algebraic-geometry, graph-theory, field-theory

It's possible for [seven points to be at integral distances](http://www.wm-archive.uni-bayreuth.de/fileadmin/Sascha/Publikationen2/rare.pdf).  I'm dallying with [powered triangles](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/WheelsOfPoweredTriangles/), though, so I'm looking for point sets where all distances are powers of a fixed $x$ value. For example, consider the root $x=1.15096...$ from $x^6 -x^2-1=0$. It's possible to set up five points in the configuration below, with the edge lengths representing $x^n$. Can 5 points be picked so that the 10 power distances are all distinct, with no three points on a line?  Without the line restrictions, it's easy.  Drop the double 3 point and extend the 0 and 5 segments to get a point with distances -2, 3, 4, and 9. Or drop the double 3, extend the 2 segment 10 away from the 027 point for a point distance 11, 12, 13 from points 018, 125, and 578.

[image: the x^6-x^2-1 pentagon]

The unit pentagon gives a less interesting solution, with $x$ being the golden ratio and all power distances 0 or 1. Can the golden ratio support a five point set with more than five distinct power lengths if no 3 points are on a line and no four points are on a circle? Various 5 point sets can be picked from the below by avoiding red lines.

[image: golden power distances]

The square root of the golden ratio, $x=\sqrt{\phi}$, as seen in the [Ammann chair](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/AmmannChair/), fares better with 7 distinct distances out of 10.

[image: ammann power distances]

What $x$ values work as well as $x^6 -x^2-1=0$, or better?

Comment: The dissected 4-5-6 triangle discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3084540/five-similar-triangles-from-4-5-6) has five external "vertices"; ignoring the incenter used to make the dissection how do the distances between A through E in that triangle fare?