# Five Similar Triangles from 4-5-6

Tags: geometry, triangles, recreational-mathematics, puzzle

A 4-5-6 triangle can be divided into 5 similar scalene triangles.  I have the solution, but I figured out it was a 4-5-6 after putting together the component triangles.  Can anyone else find it?

The [Zak triangle](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/851275) can be divided into 6 similar triangles in 2 ways. It leads to an interesting fractal.

I have a collection of unusual [similar triangle polygons](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/WheelsOfPoweredTriangles/).  I believe only three quadrilaterals can be divided into 4 similar obtuse triangles with a common vertex. One is used in the 4-5-6, the Zak triangle uses $\rho$, the [plastic constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PlasticConstant.html), the third uses $\psi$, the [supergolden ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supergolden_ratio). Below the numbers are powers of $\sqrt\psi$. This quadrilateral leads to [interesting fractals](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1286708).

[image: supergolden]

What other triangles can be divided into similar obtuse triangles in non-trivial ways?

This is related to [New Substitution Tilings Using 2, φ, ψ, χ, ρ](https://blog.wolfram.com/2019/03/07/shattering-the-plane-with-twelve-new-substitution-tilings-using-2-phi-psi-chi-rho/).

Comment: Looks like multiple questions, and isn't there an SE for puzzles?

Comment: My main question is at the end.

Comment: I'll edited the CA to remive a downvote, but somehow "sqrt(plastic)" came up.  Please correct, thanks.

Comment: There are (at least) four of the quadrilaterals you describe, because of two solutions for the 4-5-6 triangle.  See my edited answer.

Comment: Why the restriction to obtuse triangles?

Comment: I want to avoid right triangles.  There are many similar triangle dissections with right triangles.  I should change to obtuse or acute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the secondary question of the 4-5-6 triangle:

Start with $\triangle ABC$ with $|AB|=4, |AC|=5, |BC|=6$.  Bisect $\angle A$ and $\angle B$, drawing their rays to their point if intersection at the in center $I$.  From $I$ construct ray $ID$ parallel to $AC$ where $D$ lies on $BC$.  Construct point $E$ on $AC$ such that $|AE|=4$ or equivalently, $IE$ is congruent to $IB$.  Alternatively, place $E$ so that $|AE|=1$ or $DE$ is congruent to $IB$ (this alternative is shown in the diagram below).  Draw segments $IE$ and $DE$ to complete the dissection.

I have not formally proved it, but it seems to work.

[image: A diagram of 4-5-6]

---

The existence of two solutions for the 4-5-6 triangle, with either $|AE|=1$ or $|AE|=4$, implies a fourth quadrilateral divisible into four similar obtuse triangles with a common vertex.  Two of the quadrilaterals are the possible $ABDE$ quadrilaterals from the 4-5-6 triangle solutions, the other two are the quadrilaterals based on the cubic roots as given by the OP.

Comment: Yep.  I added a diagram.

Comment: $((0,0), (1,3\sqrt7)/2, (5,0), (3,\sqrt7)/2, (7,\sqrt7)/2,(1,0))$

Comment: The diagram does not match my description.  I am thinking now the solution is nonunique (you can reflect $\triangle IDE$)!

Comment: My code was looking for algebraic roots. I remember errors caused by $\sqrt2$, and this was why, I thought those two quadrilaterals were the same.